# template static function template class type deduction

Tags: c++, templates

I want to make static function in singletone template class, that would be able to deduct types of template class.
The problem is, that calling static function from template class requires explicit type.
The only workaround that I've came up with was template function instead if template member function.

Here is an example. The problem is that foo4 part is not working

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
private:
    Foo() {}
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo& operator= (const Foo&) = delete;

public:
    static auto& Instance()
    {
        static Foo foo{};
        return foo;
    }

    template<class K> static
    auto& DeductInstance(const K&)
    {
        static Foo<K> foo{};
        return foo;
    }

};

template<class K>
auto& DeductInstance(const K&)
{
    return Foo<K>::Instance();
}

void main()
{
    auto& foo1 = Foo<int>::Instance(); //OK
    auto& foo2 = Foo<int>::Instance(); //OK (return same example as foo1)
    auto& foo3 = DeductInstance(123); //OK
    auto& foo4 = Foo::DeductInstance(123); //NOT WORKING
}
```

Comment: Aside: return type of main is int

Comment: Foo is a templated class. as you need to call `auto& foo1 = Foo<int>::Instance();`, you sould call `auto& foo4 = Foo<int>::DeductInstance(123);` too, or `auto& foo4 = Foo<decltype(123)>::DeductInstance(123);`

Comment: I know, but I want Instance to automaticaly deduct types from argument

Comment: what do you really want to achieve? To "deduce" the type of `123` you could simply write `decltype(123)`

Comment: I want to deduce type of Foo<int> from Foo::Instance(123)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you're asking for is theorically possible using injected class names. That would make `Foo::` resolve to a particular, unrelated `Foo<x>::`. Here's an example:

```
struct BaseFoo {
    template<class K> static
    auto& DeductInstance(const K&);
};

template <class T>
struct Foo  {
    static auto& Instance() {
        static Foo foo{};
        return foo;
    }
};

template<>
struct Foo<void> : private BaseFoo {
    using BaseFoo::DeductInstance;
};

template<typename K>
auto& BaseFoo::DeductInstance(const K&)
{
    return Foo<K>::Instance();
}

using MakeFooAvailable = Foo<void>;

struct Dummy : MakeFooAvailable {
    auto& bar() {
        // Syntax working
        return Foo::DeductInstance(234);
    }
};
```

In the class `Dummy`, there's a injected class name for the base class `Foo`, resolving it to `Foo<void>`. Then, `Foo<void>` is making `BaseFoo::DeductInstance` available for name resolution in its scope.

---

I would advise not using this solution because it's a clever one. Clever generally mean surprising. Programmers don't expect seeing `Foo` as a non template when it is. The best solution I think would be:

```
auto& foo1 = Foo<int>::Instance(); //OK
```

The simpler, the better.

Answer (score 1):

It's 2021 and we have CTAD, but I don't think it helps. I think this is very close to what you (and I!) want:

```
// A helper struct to provide Foo with a default template 
// that isn't useful for instantiation:
struct DoNotInstantiate { DoNotInstantiate() = delete; };

template <class T = DoNotInstantiate>
class Foo
{
private:
    Foo() {
        static_assert(!std::is_same_v<T, DoNotInstantiate>, "You can't actually instantiate it with the default, it's just to make the static function work."); // Optional
    }
    // ...

public:
    // ...

    template<class K> static
    auto& DeductInstance(const K&)
    {
        static Foo<K> foo{};
        return foo;
    }
};
```

So you can call `Foo<>::DeduceInstance(bar);`. You still have to write the `<>` but otherwise, it's perfect, I think.

If you don't want that and really want to be able to call a static on a template, naming just the template name, there's this:

```
template <template<typename ...> class FooType, typename T>
auto DeduceInstance(const T& x) {
    return FooType<T>::DeduceInstance(x);
}
```

which lets you call `DeduceInstance<Foo>(x)` where `Foo` is just a template. But that feels round-about. I prefer `Foo<>::DeduceInstance(x);`.

It would be nice if CTAD let you write

```
template <class T>
Foo::DeductInstance(const T&) -> T&;
```

or maybe it would be

```
template <class T>
Foo::DeductInstance(const T&) -> Foo<T>::DeduceInstance(const T&);
```

or something similar, basically saying that if you use the template name without a type to call a static, use the argument list to dope out which template the caller was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that I dont understand completely what you are trying to do. However, you can do either of the following two:

```
struct foo {
    template <typename T> 
    static T deduce(const T& t) { 
        return {};
    }
};

template <typename T> 
T deduce_free(const T& t) {
    return {};
}

int main() {
    auto x = foo::deduce(1);
    auto y = deduce_free(1);
}
```

But you cannot call a method (whehter static or not) on some instance of `bar<T>` before you know what `T` is.

Things have changed a bit with C++17 which has [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), though <strike>as far as I know this works for constructors, so you would still need a `foo<int>` first before you could call a `foo<int>::deduce()`</strike> I am too unexperienced with that to say something not wrong ;).